# Which of the following regular expressions can be used to get the domain name? python

Tags: python, regex

Which of the following regular expressions can be used to get the domain name?

I try the next code but it doesn't work, there is something that i'm doing wrong?

> In the picture the another options

```
txt = 'I refer to https://google.com and i never refer http://www.baidu.com'
print(txt.findall(?<=https:\/\/)([A-Za-z0-9.]*))
```

[image]

Comment: You only have one regular expression. What do you mean by "which of the following"?

Comment: You're missing quotes around the regexp.

Comment: A domain name can also include the `-` character.

Comment: Hi I realized I didn't add the image but now it is ... I have those options to solve the problem, but I was testing with everyone and everyone gave me an error ... you can click to see the image

Comment: You selected the correct regexp, you just have to put it in a raw string to use it in Python.

Comment: Oh okay okay so... i don't need to put the "https" into the square bracket like i did in the code, right? or i have to do it  like is in the image?

Comment: Why would you put it into square brackets? Square brackets are for things like `[a-zA-Z0-9.]`

Comment: You didn't put it into square brackets in your code.

Comment: `[https]` matches either `h`, `t`, `p`, or `s`

Comment: You are right thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You selected the correct regexp, you just have to quote it to use it in Python. You also need to call `re.findall()`, it's not a string method.

```
import re

txt = 'I refer to https://google.com and i never refer http://www.baidu.com'
print(re.findall(r'(?<=https:\/\/)([A-Za-z0-9.]*)', txt))
```

Comment: Thank you very very much!! it was so helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that'll get your URLs

```
http(s?)://(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]
```

It'll work for https://stackoverflow.com, http://example.com, https://example.com etc...

If you don't want the http or https just use this:

```
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]
```

Comment: The question was updated with a multiple-choice quiz. He's not looking for a general solution, just the best one of the choices.